# Can't backup db: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql-9.5, pg-dump

Given:

Linux Mint 20.3

DB Client: DBeaver 22.1.4

I try to backup my Postgresql's db (my_db) by DBeaver.

But I get error:

```
/run/user/1000/doc/65139af1/bin/pg_dump --verbose --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=postgres --format=p --file /home/my_user/dev/BACKUP/my_db_local/dump-my_db-202211161718.sql -n public my_db
Task 'PostgreSQL dump' started at Wed Nov 16 17:18:29 EET 2022
/run/user/1000/doc/65139af1/bin/pg_dump: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Task 'PostgreSQL dump' finished at Wed Nov 16 17:18:29 EET 2022
2022-11-16 17:18:29.831 - IO error: Process failed (exit code = 127). See error log.
2022-11-16 17:18:29.832 - java.io.IOException: Process failed (exit code = 127). See error log.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.validateErrorCode(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:242)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.executeProcess(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:223)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.doExecute(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:262)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.lambda$0(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:83)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.RunnableContextDelegate.lambda$0(RunnableContextDelegate.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if you have installed lib **libpq.so.5** running the command:

  dconfig -p | grep libpq.so.5

If installed, something similar to this will appear....

```
libpq.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5
```

- Make sure you are not using the **flatpak** version, I had the same problem with this version, if you are using it, uninstall and download the .deb package and install from there.

https://dbeaver.io/download/